# Java Swing - whitespace appearing in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a panel that is populated with labels, and once some are added to the panel, all is well. However, after i remove everything in the panel with `panel.removeAll();` and add some more labels, this whitespace appears that is shown in the image below:

[image]

Can anyone guide me on how to remove this excess whitespace?

Comment: For best chances of getting quick decent help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) -- a *small* compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels +1 for this wonderful suggestion. I wish more new users knew about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove or add components from a container that's already visible onscreen, you must call `validate()` on the container to get the layout fixed up. Until you do, the appearance onscreen is undefined, and usually bad.

Comment: I have done: panel.removeAll(); and panel.revalidate() but still doesn't work

Comment: You also need to call repaint() on the parent.  validate() doesn't schedule a repaint to happen automatically.

Comment: do you mean repaint on the frames content pane